# SIGILL on ideone but runs with warning on Codeblocks

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, runtime-error

I was solving a simple problem on SPOJ called FASHION... its easy. I just wanted to get hang of iterators. But then I am running into a peculiar problem.

This is my code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int hotMax(vector<int> &, vector<int> &);

int main()
{
    int iter,m_f;
    scanf("%d", &iter);

    vector<int> a,b;
    while(iter--){
        scanf("%d", &m_f);
        a.resize(m_f);
        b.resize(m_f);
        vector<int>::iterator it;
        for(it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); it++){
            scanf("%d", it);
        }
        for(it = b.begin(); it != b.end(); it++){
            scanf("%d", it);
        }
        printf("%d\n", hotMax(a,b));
    }
    return 0;
}

int hotMax(vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b){
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    int result = 0;
    vector<int>::iterator it1,it2;
    for(it1 = a.begin(),it2 = b.begin(); it1 != a.end(); it1++,it2++){
        result+= (*it1) * (*it2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I get this warning on Code-blocks,

```
/home/harshal/c++ tutorial/SAMER08F/main.cpp|22|warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}

/home/harshal/c++ tutorial/SAMER08F/main.cpp|25|warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}’ [-Wformat=]|
```

These are corresponding to the 
`scanf("%d", it);`
but then it runs perfectly in codeblocks,

It gives a SIGILL in ideone and also on SPOJ.

When i replace the scanf with `cin>> *it`, it runs perfectly on SPOJ and ideone.

I shall be very thankful if you could give me an insight on this. I tried to just place **it** in the scanf, coz it's kind of a generalized pointer to the vector.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` and `printf` are legacy C functions, they should not be combined with C++ functionality like iterators. Specifically, `std::vector<T>::iterator` is implementation defined and may not simply be a `T*`, so you can not rely on that call to `scanf` being portable.

Comment: Thanks, but can you provide me the reason for SIGILL ?

Comment: Probably the compiler generates some syscall for that `scanf` call which spews everywhere when it hits whatever the implementation defines as that iterator. Hard to say though.

Comment: are you able to reproduce the same error on your end? Its bad. I know that iterator in not simply `T*` but then `cin>>*it` works.

Comment: Clang generates a `ud2` instruction for me.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator is *not* necessarily a pointer.  Thus this code produces undefined behavior:

`scanf("%d", it);`

You must give `scanf` a bonafide address of an `int` variable.  If your implementation by chance happens to consider a `std::vector<int>::iterator` a pointer, then you won't see any issues.

There is a real life example of this issue:

Back when Visual Studio 6.0 was popular, a lot of code that used `std::vector` assumed that the vector iterator was implemented as a pointer, and the programmers were right.  The vector iterator at that time was implemented as a pointer.

Then along comes Visual Studio after VS 6.0.  The vector iterator was no longer implemented as a simple pointer, thus a lot of legacy code would either not compile, or be broken if by chance they did compile.  This is what happens when you rely on implementation details when writing your programs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation